# why runtime error occurs in this code sample related about return const reference?

Tags: c++, string, reference

```
std::string const& foo()
{
    return "Hello World";
}

/*
int main()
{
    std::string str = foo(); // runtime error
}
*/


int main()
{
    foo(); // ok
}
```

why 'runtime error' occurs in this code sample but in other can work about return const reference?
the first main is error, but the second is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `foo` has undefined behavior.  It is returning a reference to a locally created object, which is destroyed when the function returns.  Your second main is *not* okay.  It happens to not exhibit any obvious visible errors in your case, but it is still wrong.

Comment: Furthermore, the more erroneous `main` is assigning a *constant* object to a *non-constant* variable, which would be a problem if the object wasn't destroyed on return.

Comment: @michaelb958: No, that's not a problem.  It's not a reference, so it just makes a copy, which is perfectly fine.  If it was a non-const reference, it simply wouldn't compile.

Comment: That's my third C/C++-related SO brainfart in 24 hours. Where has my brain gone...?

Comment: @michaelb958: It's being studied.  We'll have it back to you in 4-6 weeks.  You signed the papers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include  <windows.h>
#include  <string>

using namespace std;

std::string const  foo() {

 std::string  str = "Hello World";
 return str;

}

int main() {

 foo();                                                    // ok
 std::string str = foo();                                  // ok

}
```

Comment: When adding code to a question or answer you need to put 4 spaces in front of each line. You can also select the text and press CTRL-K and SO will add them for you. while you solution works you might want to include a description of what it's doing and why.